# PostgreSql not using index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table named snapshots with a column named data in jsonb format
An Index is created on snapshots table

`create index on snapshots using(( data->>'creator' ));`

The following query was using index initially but not after couple of days

`SELECT id, data - 'sections' - 'sharing' AS data FROM snapshots WHERE data->>'creator' = 'abc@email.com' ORDER BY xmin::text::bigint DESC`

below is the output by running explain analyze

```
Sort  (cost=19.10..19.19 rows=35 width=77) (actual time=292.159..292.163 rows=35 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (((xmin)::text)::bigint) DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
  ->  Seq Scan on snapshots  (cost=0.00..18.20 rows=35 width=77) (actual time=3.500..292.104 rows=35 loops=1)
        Filter: ((data ->> 'creator'::text) = 'abc@email.com'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 152
Planning Time: 0.151 ms
Execution Time: 292.198 ms
```

Comment: How many rows has the table? Using an index and then reading data from other columns can be useless with small table or even with big table with small cardinality.

Comment: It has 187 rows, and the total size of table is 88 MB as data column has large amount of data as it has images stored in it

Comment: The output of `explain(analyze, BUFFERS, TIMING)` would interesting to see (especially if you can do `set track_io_timing=on;' before that). 200ms to scan such a tiny table seems quite slow - but if the values are large, that might be an explanation.

Comment: Try to execute your query with `set enable_seqscan=off;` this will force Postgres to use the index if it can. If it the does use the index, that means the statistics suggest to the optimizer that a seqscan may be faster. try `vacuum analyse` to regenerate the statistics.

Comment: Just want to add one thing I had resolved this issue once by dropping the index and recreating it.

Comment: Sort  (cost=19.10..19.19 rows=35 width=77) (actual time=347.721..347.725 rows=35 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (((xmin)::text)::bigint) DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
  Buffers: shared hit=6235
  ->  Seq Scan on snapshots  (cost=0.00..18.20 rows=35 width=77) (actual time=2.884..347.660 rows=35 loops=1)
        Filter: ((data ->> 'creator'::text) = 'abc@email.com'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 152
        Buffers: shared hit=6235
Planning Time: 0.099 ms
Execution Time: 347.764 ms   explain(analyze, BUFFERS, TIMING) but without set track_io_timing=on @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

A table with 187 rows is very small. For very small tables, a sequential scan is the most efficient strategy.

What is surprising here is the long duration of the query execution (292 milliseconds!). Unless you have incredibly lame or overloaded storage, this must mean that the table is extremely bloated – it is comparatively large, but almost all pages are empty, with only 187 live rows. You should rewrite the table to compact it:

```
VACUUM (FULL) snapshots;
```

Then the query will become must faster.

Comment: Is the above select query most efficient, or can it be improved to even more faster query if i only want to select 2 fields from data column(jsonb)?

Comment: Its still not using index, i have executed vacuum analyze.

Comment: I was talking about `VACUUM (FULL)`. The execution plan is good, what is bad is the long time ut takes to read 187 rows from the table. There is no advantage in using an index here.